# Column of buttons to the right

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

In the DataGrid I want to append a column of buttons from the right side (to the most right column). my looks like:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TableView}" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>                  
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Add">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.AddItemCommand}" >Add</Button>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Table looks like:

[image]

But, I need the buttons to be on the right side.

Note: The datagid is bind to DataTable, I will know the column names and columns count only at runtime

Comment: Have you tried setting the Button HorizontalAlignment property to the right?

Comment: @GuidoC. This is not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `AutoGeneratedColumns` event and either add the `DataGridTemplateColumn` or set its `DisplayIndex` property programmatically:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
    dataGrid.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = dataGrid.Columns.Count - 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < dataGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
        dataGrid.Columns[i].DisplayIndex = i;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TableView}" CanUserAddRows="False"
          AutoGeneratedColumns="DataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Add">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.AddItemCommand}" >Add</Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```